# What distinguishes the difference states of matter from solid to BEC and perhaps fermionic condensate?

Tags: states-of-matter, matter

Is it something to do with the behavior of electrons? How many states are there either discovered or predicted?

Comment: This is too broad.

Comment: @hft I do not want a description of all the possible states of matter, I need some guidelines or rules so that we all can agree and draw a distinctive line to separate them from 1 states to another.

Comment: This question is likely too broad or otherwise too ill-posed to receive a good answer in this forum. You don't have to edit it, but if you want to receive a good answer from someone it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 無

'States of matter' is a question of taxonomy, not of reality, and moreover, it's a result of the conditions surrounding the matter, not its internal properties. Certain combinations of properties give us a hint towards calling something 'solid' or 'liquid', but in truth there are no lines, just a continuous spectrum, and under certain conditions, matter transitions seamlessly through all sorts of states, both mundane and exotic:

### Behold: Jupiter

A perfect example of this is Jupiter. Composed primarily of hydrogen, this gas giant consists (conjecturally) of a core of high-temperature hydrogen ice, floating in liquid hydrogen, enveloped in hydrogen gas, moving through interplanetary medium composed of hydrogen plasma.

Except not really: Under these conditions, the classical notions of states of matter break down entirely: Between these states of matter there are no interfaces, just a gradual, continuous transition.

In other words: The distinctive line to separate one state from another you are after doesn't *really* exist.

Comment: Hrm? Phase transitions are definitely a real phenomenon. Certainly they aren't present in all systems, and the solid/liquid/gas trichotomy can totally break down. But it's not true that everything changes continuously always.

Comment: @SirElderberry Rephrasing that comment: The sharp phase transitions we know are apparent and emergent phenomena of special conditions, not the smooth transitions seen elsewhere.